# What's the difference between RabbitMQ and Pusher?

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, pusher

I'm building a django webapp where i need to stream some stock market trades on a webpage in real time. In order to do that, i'm searching for various approaches, and i found about Pusher and RabbitMQ.

With RabbitMQ i would just send the message to RMQ and consume them from Django, in order to get them on the web page. While looking for other solutions, i've also found about Pusher. What it's not clear, to me, is the difference between the two, technically. I don't understand where would i use Rabbit and where would i use Pusher, can someone explain to me how are they different? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You may be thinking of data delivery, non-blocking operations or push
  notifications. Or you want to use publish / subscribe, asynchronous
  processing, or work queues. All these are patterns, and they form
  part of messaging.
- RabbitMQ is a messaging broker - an intermediary for messaging. It
  gives your applications a common platform to send and receive
  messages, and your messages a safe place to live until received.
- Pusher is a hosted service that makes it super-easy to add real-time data and functionality to web and mobile applications.
- Pusher sits as a real-time layer between your servers and your
  clients. Pusher maintains persistent connections to the clients -
  over WebSocket if possible and falling back to HTTP-based
  connectivity - so that as soon as your servers have new data that
  they want to push to the clients they can do, instantly via Pusher.
- Pusher offers libraries to integrate into all the main runtimes and
  frameworks. PHP, Ruby, Python, Java, .NET, Go and Node on the server
  and JavaScript, Objective-C (iOS) and Java (Android) on the client.